# Use non-local variables in actionlistener

Tags: java, icons, actionlistener

I want use a variable in action listener of it .
this is my code :

```
public class Face {

public Face(){

    Btn1 =  new JToggleButton();
    Btn2 =  new JToggleButton();
    Btn3 =  new JToggleButton();
    Btn4 =  new JToggleButton();
    Btn5 =  new JToggleButton();
    Btn6 =  new JToggleButton();

}


public Start6(){

    JToggleButton[] Btn = new javax.swing.JToggleButton[5]; // An array for saving address of all buttons

    Btn[0] = Btn1 ;
    Btn[1] = Btn2 ;
    Btn[2] = Btn3 ;
    Btn[3] = Btn4 ;
    Btn[4] = Btn5 ;
    Btn[5] = Btn6 ;

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 36 ; i++) {
        Btn[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Btn[i].setSize(150, 150);
        ImageIcon BtnImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/GameImages/" + /* a picture name*/ + ".jpg" ));
        Image img = BtnImage.getImage();
        Btn[i].setIcon( new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(225,160 ,Image.SCALE_FAST)));
        X6P.add(Btn[i]);
        }
    });
    }


   }
  public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn1;
  public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn2;
  public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn3;
  public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn4;
  public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn5;
  }
```

when i want use from Btn array in action listener of Btn array (same arrays) i get this error :

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
>   i want when button clicked  show it's icon ...

Comment: so... declare them as `final`if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says: your array variable `Btn` is not `final`, so it cannot be accessed from the inner class. Making it `final` will fix the problem:

```
final JToggleButton[] Btn = new ...
```

Another solution would be moving the array into the class:

```
public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn1;
public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn2;
public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn3;
public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn4;
public javax.swing.JToggleButton Btn5;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton[] Btn = new javax.swing.JToggleButton[] {
    Btn1, Btn2, Btn3, Btn4, Btn5
};
```

This would do exactly the same thing, and make your code shorter.

> I want when button clicked show its icon

You don't need to use the array at all: rather than referencing `Btn[i]`, reference `e.getSource()`. It is set to the button that has been clicked - all you need to do is to cast it:

```
javax.swing.JToggleButton sender = (javax.swing.JToggleButton)e.getSource();
```

Create one action listener *outside* the loop, and set it on all your buttons. This would eliminate the array altogether:

```
// The same listener instance can handle all buttons
ActionListener actListener = new ActionListener() {     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        javax.swing.JToggleButton senderButton = (javax.swing.JToggleButton)e.getSource();
        ... // Do anything you want with senderButton here
    }
};
// Add the same listener to all buttons
for (int i = 0 ; i < 36 ; i++) {
    Btn[i].addActionListener(actListener);
}
```

Comment: thank you .

what does work e.getSource(); for me ?

can you show me how can i create buttons that with click show it's icons ??

and i want know whom buttons is selected .

thanks again ...